# CKEditor.replace, CKEditor gives the error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

CKEditor was working fine when called as follows `CKEDITOR.inline`. Since the toolbar was not properly aligned with the editable area, changed the call to `CKEDITOR.replace`. This displays CKEDITOR on the browser but will not allow editing. The buttons on toolbar are selectable.

For `inline` and `replace` I am using the `id` of a `TextArea` tag. The error that I get is

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection'
>   of undefined
>       at CKEDITOR.dom.selection.getNative (ckeditor.js:427)
>       at CKEDITOR.dom.selection (ckeditor.js:425)
>       at a.CKEDITOR.editor.getSelection (ckeditor.js:423)
>       at CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.Image (ckeditor.js:1111)
>       at CKEDITOR.plugins.undo.UndoManager.save (ckeditor.js:1106)
>       at a. (ckeditor.js:1102)
>       at a.m (ckeditor.js:10)
>       at a.CKEDITOR.event.CKEDITOR.event.fire (ckeditor.js:12)
>       at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
>       at a.setData (ckeditor.js:260)

Comment: "`CKEDITOR.inline` Since the toolbar was not properly aligned" - maybe your styles are too aggressive and conflict with editor styles.

“`CKEDITOR.replace` … but will not allow editing” -  Please post the code for your `textarea` and for CKEditor plus its configuration.

Comment: The CKEDITOR is placed in the html as a CCA. The html is as follows

Comment: <div class="oj-flex-item">
     <psc-input-ckeditor   data-bind="attr:{id: 'contextHelpDetail_'+ contextHelpDetailModel.ContxthlpClob.fieldName, 
      fieldname: contextHelpDetailModel.ContxthlpClob.fieldName, rest: contextHelpDetailModel.ContxthlpClob.rest, 
     inputid: contextHelpDetailModel.ContxthlpClob.fieldName}",
component="{{contextHelpDetailModel.ContxthlpClob.richEditorComponent}}"></psc-input-ckeditor>                
</div>

Comment: This is the html on the CCA which would be used for the above CCA html
<div class='oj-form-control oj-flex  '>
    <div class='oj-flex-item  ' data-bind="attr:{id: inputID + 'wrapper'}">
        <textarea  data-bind="attr:{id:inputID}"   name="editor1"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: HTML loos fine but if the toolbar is not properly aligned it has to do with CSS used rather than HTML. You could try disabling few CSS rules using browser developer tools when page is displayed - this could help you find the conflicting class or style as when you remove it you should see that toolbar gets aligned properly.